# Unique browser ID

Tags: angular, spring

I have an angular application running on the front end where the backend is developed using spring boot. And for every request I send to the backend I want to set the browser id in the header of the request. We considering two chromes open in the same machine then both of the machines will be having the same session. And if the browsers are open on two different computers the sessions will be different as well. The request ID is unique within the browser session. I want a code to be written on the client side to obtain the browser id.

Comment: Why do you need this ? Trust a client is never a good idea.

Comment: The reason is if the user doesnt have a device id when logging in then an otp is sent to that user. So once he logins again from the same device on another attempt then i want to uniquely identify that user and not to send then the otp to that particular user.